# enumeration values not handled in switch

Tags: 64-bit, warnings, c++builder, enumeration, c++builder-xe5

When compiling my project as a 64bit target (this isn't considered a warning on 32bit target) I get this warning:

```
5 enumeration values not handled in switch: 'kCreated', 'kLoaded', 'kConnected'...
```

I have somehow managed to turn off the error/warning message numbers, so I don't know what number to suppress in my code with `#pragma warn`.

I need to use `#pragma warn` because I only want to suppress approved places in my code (turning the warning off and on again).

Bonus question: Does anyone know how to get back the error/warning numbers again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 64bit compiler is based on CLang, which does not use warning numbers, which is why you do not see them.  The following info comes from Bruneau Babet, one of C++Builder's chief developers, in the Embarcadero forums:

[How do I suppress 64bit XE3 warnings?](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=83062#533277)

> Warnings in clang, hence bcc64, don't have the Wxxxx numbers. Behind the
> scene there is a unique id generated for each warning but it's
> auto-generated and cannot be assumed to remain constant across builds.
> Instead each warning has a group. Related warnings are often in the same
> group. Some groups have just one warning. To disable warnings of a group
> you can use "-Wno-" on the command line, or via something like
> the following in code:
>
> `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-W<groupname>".`
>
> For example, the first warning you listed is under the group "float-equal".
> So, "-Wno-float-equal" should disable that warning. And **to disable the one
> about an enumerator not handled in the switch you can use the following in
> code:**
>
> `#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wswitch"`
>
> So the next obvious question is how to find out about each group. The
> "-fdiagnostics-show-option" should trigger the compiler to display the
> option but unfortunately the IDE does not honor that option. So you must
> either use the command line to find out about the group ach warning belongs
> to, or you can peek at the Warning declarations here:
>
> https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/clang/include/clang/Basic
>
> The *.td files declare the various warnings. The ones mentioned above are
> https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tree/main/clang/include/clang/Basic/DiagnosticSemaKinds.td

Oddly, `#pragma clang` is still not documented on the [Embarcadero DocWiki](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Pragma_Directives_Overview_Index).

Comment: I assume `#pragma clang diagnostic warning "-Wswitch"` will turn it back on again, or?

Comment: I do not know. I have never used `#pragma clang` before. There is no mention of any `#pragma clang diagnostic warning` option in the [CLang User's Manual](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html).  It does, however, mention `#pragma clang diagnostic push` and `#pragma clang diagnostic pop`, so you can use those with `#pragma clang diagnostic ignore` to temporarily disable warnings and then re-enable them, at least.

Comment: I tried the `#pragma clang diagnostic warning "-Wswitch"` and it seems to work as intended (turning on the warning again). I got the hint about warning when I removed `ignored`. It showed me a couple of options it was looking for, `warning` was one of them.

Comment: Now when my program finally runs through the 64bit compiler, I can't link because I have a custom made component library and so far we can't compile 64bit components in C++ Builder... sight, so much for that 64bit porting...

Comment: More accurately, you cannot *compile* 64bit **packages** in C++Builder yet, but you can *consume* 64bit Delphi packages, and you do not technically need to use packages in order to use components in general.  You could simply instantiate the components in code instead.

Comment: You mean I can get around it by simply include my custom controls source code and create them in runtime instead? I guess that is another way to deal with it... Thanks for the input...